# Is it possible to differentiate generic and targeted infection?

Tags: malware

Details: my USB stick got infected and probably my computer too. I suspect that the person I asked to transfer the file did it intentionally. But the problem is I don't know what is their intention. Avast found bunch of malware, Trojan, worm. I researched a bit and came to conclusion that it's not possible to be sure that AV got all harmful stuff and that it's not possible to know my files are not infected so I can't back them up.

This is a public place so I can compare with other people or  go back there and plug my USB in, and compare the results with previous infection. But how do I do that or is that possible?

Also would my IT department take me seriously or they'll think I'm nuts?

Comment: upload the malware to virus total.If its a generic infection it will be well know already.If the person intentionally wrote a malware to infect you then it wont be that well known or even get caught by AV so quickly.

Comment: How can I do that in a safe environment? Avast don't let me recover infected file, has put others to virus chest. Thanks for commenting.